# Improve my cron script for website change notification

Tags: bash, web, cron, notifications

I've been using a script through `cron` to check if a web page has changed.

Everything is running smoothly but this is my first attempt and I know it could be better. I'm a noob so take it easy.

I've hobbled this together through many sources. The standard services that check if a webpage has changed didn't work on my webpage of instance because each instance created a new shopping cart ID. Instead, I looked for alike with say `article:modified_time` that was my `TextofInterest` and it will grab that whole line and compare it to the same line in the prior file.

Things to maybe do better:

1. I'd like to define each file (`.txt`, `.html`, websites) at the beginning.
2. I've also run into some other code where it looks like it might not have to save to a file and run in memory?
3. Currently saving to a flash drive (open media vault), I'd like to change the directory to a different drive for the writes of the files.

Any other improvements are welcome.

Here is working code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cp Current.html Prior.html
wget -O Current.html 'https://websiteofinterest.com/
awk '/TextOfInterest/' Prior.html > Prior.txt
awk '/TextOfInterest/' Current.html > Current.txt
diff -q Current.txt Prior.txt || diff Current.txt Prior.txt | mail -s "Website Canged" "Emailtosendto@email.com"
```

Comment: `awk '/TextOfInterest/' somefile.html > somefile.txt` might suffice. (Which `grep` might do without the slashes.)

Comment: To call `awk` only once (because the fewer `fork()`s the better and whatnot), you could use this hack: `awk '/TextOfInterest/ {print > substr(FILENAME, 1, index(FILENAME, ".")) "txt"}' Prior.html Current.html` But it’s ugly, so … probably not worth it.

Comment: Sweet! Yes the 
awk '/TextOfInterest/' is much cleaner and works.